# Accessing UIImage inside Array with indexPath & Creating Empty UIImage Array Element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, nsindexpath

I have an array of UIImages. I want to create it with 3 empty empty array elements (of UIImage)

```
var newImages = [UIImage]()
```

**First Question:** How can I get it like this?

```
let newImages = [emptyUIImage,emptyUIImage,emptyUIImage]
```

Or is there a way to store empty array element for UIImage array, as I stored like this, empty NSURL for NSURL array?

```
if data.count != 3 {
    let emptyURL = NSURL(string: "")
    data.append(emptyURL!)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of any type with a fixed number of elements and then use `array[i] = value` to set the value for the `i`th index in your array

```
//instead of passing 10 you could pass, for example, array.count
  var images = [UIImage](count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)


images[0] = //someImage
images[3] = //someImage
images[1] = //someImage
```

Alternatively you could make your array an array of optional UIImages like this...

```
var newImages = [UIImage?]()
```

and then append nil where there is an empty image...

`newImages.append(nil)`

Comment: Thanks however, is there a way that I assign a nil value which would print like `[ , , uiimage]` ? Also, do you have any idea about how to access it like I did for `data` in moveDataItem()? How to make `self.newImages[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)` work?

Comment: Updated answer to address first concern. As to making that work, it looks like you are accessing an array index, and then calling `removeAtIndex(_:Int)` on that index? It would work if you did `self.data.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)`, assuming that `data` is an array and `fromIndexPath.item` is an Int

Comment: Big thanks for the first part of the question! How can I deal with the second part? Is there a way I can achieve the same process it's achieving while reordering array elements for my UIImage array?

Comment: do you mean while NOT reordering array elements? or did you mean it the way you said it? You may want to open up another question

Comment: What this function helps me to accomplish is that when I reorder the collectionViewCells by dragging on the view, this function helps me to keep track of the rearrangements in the array. So, after running everything in this function each time, if I put print(self.data) at the end of the function, it prints the new order of the array. So I think I need to do the exactly same things for UIImages array. With your answer, I created the UIImage array with 3 empty elements. If user uploads an image, the UIImage array get filled depending on the index. But then, if cells get rearranged...

Comment: Part 2: ...I want track the same reordering that I do for data, also for my UIImage array..

Comment: Ok i think i know what your goal is. Seems a little tricky for sure but there must be a simple way to handle this. Basically you have two arrays. One of them is able to be re-ordered by the user, and the other array must adjust its order according to the way the user has re-arranged the first array... is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly right.. If I can manage to add the array inside the function under data, and make my UIImage array to work with these 3 lines, I think it would work.. But I couldn't :/

Comment: I cleaned up this question and created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757509/reordering-elements-inside-array-of-uiimage)