# Reordering Elements inside Array of UIImage

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsindexpath

I have an array of NSURL array, and I am able to use functions `removeAtIndex` and `insert`. I know the `fromIndexPath` and `toIndexPath` and this method helps me to accomplish the same for [[NSURL]] using this Delegate method (check `var data` below):

```
func moveDataItem(fromIndexPath : NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      let name = self.data[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.item]
      self.data[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)
      self.data[toIndexPath.section].insert(name, atIndex: toIndexPath.item)

     // do same for UIImage array
}
```

However, I have an array of UIImage with 3 empty elements with running.

```
var newImages = [UIImage?]()

 viewDidLoad() {
    newImages.append(nil)
    newImages.append(nil)
    newImages.append(nil)
 }
```

**My question is** how can I use the `newImages` array inside `moveDataItem()`, as well as the `data` and be able to run that lines for rearranging the order for UIImage array.

I tried these but unfortunately I couldn't make them work..

```
self.newImages[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)
// and
self.newImages[fromIndexPath.row].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)
```

---

For clarification, the data array looks like this

```
lazy var data : [[NSURL]] = {

    var array = [[NSURL]]()
    let images = self.imageURLsArray

    if array.count == 0 {

        var index = 0
        var section = 0


        for image in images {
            if array.count <= section {
                array.append([NSURL]())
            }
            array[section].append(image)

            index += 1
        }
    }
    return array
}()
```

Comment: So you're wanting a method that generically moves around a 2D array?

Comment: Yes, I want to do the same that I am doing for `data` inside `moveDataItem()`  also for `UIImage array`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for rearranging any 2d array:

```
func move<T>(fromIndexPath : NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath, items:[[T]]) -> [[T]] {

    var newData = items

    if newData.count > 1 {
        let thing = newData[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.item]
        newData[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)
        newData[toIndexPath.section].insert(thing, atIndex: toIndexPath.item)
    }
    return newData
}
```

example usage:

```
var things = [["hi", "there"], ["guys", "gals"]]

// "[["hi", "there"], ["guys", "gals"]]\n"
print(things)

things = move(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), toIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow:1, inSection:  0), items: things)

// "[["there", "hi"], ["guys", "gals"]]\n"
print(things)
```

And this will work with a normal array:

```
func move<T>(fromIndex : Int, toIndex: Int, items:[T]) -> [T] {

    var newData = items

    if newData.count > 1 {
        let thing = newData[fromIndex]
        newData.removeAtIndex(fromIndex)
        newData.insert(thing, atIndex: toIndex)
    }
    return newData
}
```

Comment: It's a delegate function and everything works for `data`. The problem was adapting the UIImage array inside the `moveDataItem()`. I think you got me wrong. :/ I edited my question a bit to clarify more

Comment: yeah, I re-read your question and noticed that. Added a function for a 1D array

Comment: So should I create another delegate method (your last example) and call it when I call moveDataItem method? Is this the right approach to take? I want to overwrite the UIImage array with the new order.

Comment: The design pattern is up to you. Without knowing your app I can't really give an opinion, but your idea should work as far as I know

Comment: Mutating version as an extension on `Array` if you want to add it to your answer (or I can write another).

`extension Array where Element : _ArrayType {
    mutating func move(from fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, to toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        let first = self[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.row]
        let second = self[toIndexPath.section][toIndexPath.row]
        
        self[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.row] = second
        self[toIndexPath.section][toIndexPath.row] = first
    }
}`

Comment: @Kevin, can you please add it as another answer.. It looks messy here.. I think with your approach, I'd be able to use my UIImage array inside moveDataItem() delegate method. Am I right? However, I couldn't understand what you did with extension + where. Can you please add a bit of explanation too?

Comment: That would allow you to modify an existing array yes

Comment: @Kevin, I placed the extension (your chunk) above the ViewController class. But how can I call it inside method and make it modify newImages (UIImage) array? I tried calling `newImages.move(from: fromIndexPath, to: toIndexPath)` but I receive error `Value of type [UIImage?] has no member 'Distance'`